# How can I get the local notification settings of a user in iOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a method which returns a boolean for whether or not the user has authorized notifications. Currently I have this:

```
func notificationsAllowed() -> Bool{
            var valToRet = false
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings() { settings in
                valToRet = (settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
                print(settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
            }
            return valToRet
        }
```

I am not quite understanding what "settings in" does. This method is not working because valToRet is never updated. My target was to make a method which gets me this information, but I'm seeing that this actually shows some major holes in my understanding of the swift language, so I'd like to learn what is actually happening. I'm having trouble finding resources for how Swift's syntax works in this way, any references would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `getNotificationSettings` function of `UNUserNotificationCenter` is async and has a completion handler as its only parameter.

The function signature is: `func getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationSettings) -> Void)`

What this means is that the same call as in your code can be written as:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) -> Void in
    valToRet = (settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
    print(settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
})
```

What this means is that your function `notificationsAllowed()` returns before `getNotificationSettings()` fires its callback and therefore `valToRet` is always false.

Therefore, you're function `notificationsAllowed()` is redundant and you should just use `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings()` in its place, waiting for the completion handler closure. I expect you'll have to restructure where this code is called as I think you've made the assumption this value is available immediately.

If you call this in `viewDidAppear` (not recommended, you should always request authorisation once a users action requires auth - e.g. they could click a "Subscribe" button), code could be:

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) -> Void in
        if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            // Display dialog advertising benefits of push notifications
            // Encourage user to allow, then present auth prompt
            // ...
        }
    })
}
```

### Extra

> I am not quite understanding what "settings in" does.

In Swift, the `in` keyword is used to declare the beginning of closures (anonymous functions). For standard functions we have `func`, although a closure (anonymous function) we have to use `in` to declare.

Think of it as "Take the parameter `settings` and use it `in` this bit of throw away code".

So the completion handler from earlier for `getNotificationSettings` could in theory be written as a standard function, rather than a anonymous closure`, like:

```
func myNotificationSettingsCompletionHandler(settings: UNNotificationSettings) -> Void {
    if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
        // Display dialog advertising benefits of push notifications
        // Encourage user to allow, then present auth prompt
        // ...
    }
}
```

We can then use that function in the `completionHandler:` param of `getNotificationSettings` like:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: myNotificationSettingsCompletionHandler)
```